# An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (ASC5.predict.deps.json) was not found

Tags: c#

i tried to run my C# after i put it to release mode. when i debugged it, it was fine. but after when i release and tried to run my program in my other server, this error shows up.

An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (ASC5.predict.deps.json) was not found:
package: 'System.Data.SqlClient', version: '4.8.2'
path: 'runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp2.1/System.Data.SqlClient.dll'

i have the System.Data.SqlClient package installed before i build it.
am i missing something here? and do i need to download this package?